# Does the search tool search through comments as well?

Tags: feature-request, search

Does the search tool search through comments as well?

For example, I'm searching the phrase "I am not sure this is exactly like an AL", which is in the first comment to the question [How to create the equivalent of an Adjustment Layer in an editor that does not support it?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/13383/1024), but the results don't show this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the advanced search tools page (just hit enter in the search box) allows you to search the site using Google, which does find the post you mention straight away - it also *already* finds this post...